# How can I display template who is saved in localstorage? (Angular Material)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have problem with displaying templates in Angular Material. I want to save to localstorage my template who I choose in menu, but my app display another template (dafault template) after refresh page. How can I save template to localstorage in this example?

Source app:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-event-emitting-to-change-theme-localstorage?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Do you know how resolve this thing? Thank you very much!

Comment: do you want to know how to store values in local storage?

Comment: Values was stored in Localstorage but template who I choose not load after refresh page.

Comment: I think that some problem is in app.component.ts but I don't know how resolve this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you loading the theme anywhere.

I would do it in `ngOnInit` for `navbar.component.ts`:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('themes');
  if (selectedTheme) {
    this.selectedTheme.emit(selectedTheme);
  }
}
```

Here's an updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-event-emitting-to-change-theme-localstorage-9l9gqa?file=src/app/navbar/navbar.component.ts